# × TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. Mern stack post request with fetch not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am getting this error with a MERN stack that I m working on
when trying to send a post request to create a new user in MongoDB. I am getting this error. I am not sure why this is happening and it is discouraging to say the least. I've only been coding for about 6 months

```
  TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
  handleSubmit
  src/components/auth/RegistrationForm.js:27
  24 |   email: {email},
  25 |   password: {password}
  26 | }
   > 27 | create(user).then((response) => {
    | ^  28 |   if (response.error) {
    29 |     console.log(response)
    30 |   }
```

here is the registration form

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Button, CustomInput, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import Divider from '../common/Divider';
import SocialAuthButtons from './SocialAuthButtons';
import withRedirect from '../../hoc/withRedirect';
import axios from 'axios'
import create from '../../user/api-user';
const RegistrationForm = ({ setRedirect, setRedirectUrl, layout, hasLabel }) => {
  // State
  
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

  // Handler
   const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const user = {
      email: {email},
      password: {password}
    }
    create(user).then((response) => {
      if (response.error) {
        console.log(response)
      }
    })
      

    toast.success(`Successfully registered as ${email}`);
    setRedirect(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setRedirectUrl(`/authentication/${layout}/login`);
  }, [setRedirectUrl, layout]); // the array are dependencies that trigger the function setREdirectUrl. good to know

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled( !email || !password || !confirmPassword || !isAccepted || password !== confirmPassword);
  }, [ email, password, confirmPassword, isAccepted]);

  return ( 
  <>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      
      <FormGroup>
        {hasLabel && <Label>Email address</Label>}
        <Input
          placeholder={!hasLabel ? 'Email address' : ''}
          value={email}
          onChange={({ target }) => setEmail(target.value)}
          type="email"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <div className="form-row">
        <FormGroup className="col-6">
          {hasLabel && <Label>Password</Label>}
          <Input
            placeholder={!hasLabel ? 'Password' : ''}
            value={password}
            onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
            type="password"
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="col-6">
          {hasLabel && <Label>Confirm Password</Label>}
          <Input
            placeholder={!hasLabel ? 'Confirm Password' : ''}
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChange={({ target }) => setConfirmPassword(target.value)}
            type="password"
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>

      <CustomInput
        id="customCheckTerms"
        label={
          <Fragment>
            I accept the <Link to="#!">terms</Link> and <Link to="#!">privacy policy</Link>
          </Fragment>
        }
        checked={isAccepted}
        onChange={({ target }) => setIsAccepted(target.checked)}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <FormGroup>
        <Button color="primary" block className="mt-3" disabled={isDisabled}>
          Register
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
      <Divider className="mt-4">or register with</Divider>     
    </Form>
    <div>
      <Form>
    <SocialAuthButtons /> 
    </Form>
    </div>
  </>
 
    
  );
};

RegistrationForm.propTypes = {
  setRedirect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setRedirectUrl: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  layout: PropTypes.string,
  hasLabel: PropTypes.bool
};

RegistrationForm.defaultProps = {
  layout: 'basic',
  hasLabel: false
};

export default withRedirect(RegistrationForm);
```

here is the api-user.js

```
import React from 'react'


const create = async (user) => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('/api/user/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        return await response.json()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

export default { create }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when exporting page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633491/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-when-exporting-page)

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting the create method in an `Object`. So, you simply can't invoke the function like this.

The solution is:

```js
import { create } from '../../user/api-user';
```

Or, you can do this:

```js
import UserApi from '../../user/api-user';

UserApi.create(user).then(...).catch(...);
```